# dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue() not firing after NSMutableURLRequest with timeoutInterval

Tags: ios, grand-central-dispatch, nsmutableurlrequest

I am using the following (simplified) GCD call in my app:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0), ^{

    NSString *query = "/api/something";
    NSString *parameters = "a=1234&b=5678";   

    _myDict = (NSMutableDictionary*)[NetworkUtility postDataToServer:query withParameters:parameters];  


        // Done with API Call
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

            // Do something

        });

});
```

When the call is made to `NetworkUtility`, a NSURL Connection is called is made to:

```
 NSData *postData = [parameters dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
 NSString *postLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu",(unsigned long)[postData length]];

 NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"https://myapp.com%@", query];

 NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString] cachePolicy:NSURLRequestReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData timeoutInterval:7.0];

 [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
 [request setValue:postLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
 [request setValue:@"application/x-www-form-urlencoded" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
 [request setHTTPBody:postData];

 NSData *response = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];

 return response;
```

The result is that if the network receives a response, the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` block fires as expected, but if the network call times out and the `_recommendationDictionary` is nil, the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` never fires.

Why does `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()` not fire immediately, if the `NetworkUtility` is returning a value?

Comment: What if you put a breakpoint on `return response;` and then step out of the method?  What gets executed next?

Comment: @PhillipMills when I step through it, it hits `return response`, then goes back to the `dispatch_async` block as expected, then hits the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),`, and seems to skip to the end that block without touching anything in the block.

Comment: Because that block is executed asynchronously you wouldn't expect the debugger to enter the block at that point. Set another breakpoint inside that block to determine if it is executed

Comment: Umm... Ok seems like it is hitting that code. I will inspect further and let you know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block is *enqueued* on the main queue.  The main queue is a serial queue, and it will execute the enqueued blocks in order.

If you use a CFRunLoop on the main thread, then the main dispatch queue is drained in that run loop, so if the run loop is occupied with other activity, it will also cause a delay in executing those blocks.

If you don't actually need to do UI or other activities that are serialized on the main thread, you're probably best off not using the main queue.